# Use MapBox GL JS with Angular - Error: Invalid type: ‘container’ must be a String or HTMLElement

Tags: angular, mapbox-gl-js

I was working on a angular project using mapbox gl, I want to add my current location into my map. I went thought their documentation and found a way to do it [in the quickstart guide](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/), but that code was not working in my angular project.It always giving me the above error. please I am new to mapbox and angular help me.

```js
import { Component, OnInit,AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl'; // or "const mapboxgl = require('mapbox-gl');"


@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
   
    constructor() {
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 
         'api key'
            const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // stylesheet location
            center:  [79.861244,6.927079], // starting position [lng, lat]
            zoom: 9 // starting zoom
        });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

   
}
```

```html
<div id='map'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys I found a solution, first of all we have to wait until the view initialized, therefore we have to implement our HomeCompenet with AfterViewInit interface. After that we can access the DOM object using javascript, according to the Mapbox GL documentation [enter link description here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/) container attribute should be a html element there for we have to access the element that we want to render our map object and we have use angular type assertion to convert it to html object.

```js
import { Component, OnInit,AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl'; // or "const mapboxgl = require('mapbox-gl');"


@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {
    mapContainer:HTMLElement;
    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.mapContainer= (<HTMLElement>document.getElementById('map'));
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 
         'api key'
            const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: this.mapContainer,
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // stylesheet location
            center:  [79.861244,6.927079], // starting position [lng, lat]
            zoom: 9 // starting zoom
        });
    }
}
```